setting up the python based project and run the project in AWS sagemaker studio classic
I have a python project available in git.
I have cloned the project in AWS sagemaker studio classic.
i have created the conda environment with python 3.11 , but when i verified the python version, it is showing base environment python version.
my question is, how to point to the newly created python version and not able find the option to run the project and project has several directories and files and could not able to resolve the dependencies.
can someone advise on this.
